Tiling of a tree to show that a group acting freely on a tree is free
Let me start giving some context:
Let $G$ be a group acting freely on a tree $T$. Let $T'$ be the barycentric subdivision of $T$ (that is, the graph obtained by placing a new vertex at the center of each edge of the original graph).
A tile is a subtree $T_0$ of $T'$. And
a tiling of $T$ is a collection of tiles with the following properties:

No two tiles share an edge, so two tiles can only intersect at one vertex.
The union of the tiles is the entire tree $T'$.

I am reading a proof of the fact that if a group $G$ acts freely on a tree, then $G$ is a free group. I can follow most of the proof, but there is a detail that is not explicitely written and I am having a lot of trouble trying to see why it should be true. It has to do with  how they find a tiling of a tree.
Apart from conditions 1 and 2, in this proof they require:

There is a single tile $T_0$ so that the set of tiles is equal to  $\{g\cdot T_0:g\in G\}$.

So, the way they give such a tiling in the proof is:
Fix $v$ a vertex of $T$. For each element $g$ of $G$, we take $T_g$ to be the subtree of the barycentric subdivision $T$ whose vertex set is the set of vertices $w$ of $T'$ so that $d(w, gv) \leq d(w, hv)$
for all $h\in G$ and whose edge set is the set of edges $e$ of $T'$
so that both vertices of $e$ lie in $T_g$ (the distance here is the path metric on T'). In the proof, it is claimed that the collection $\{T_g\}$ is a tiling of $T$.
MY QUESTION: How can they be sure that condition 1 holds for this collection of subtrees? (I have no problems with conditions 2 and 3).
Any ideas would be very useful to understand fully the proof. Thanks in advance.

How do you define the action on $T'$? It appears there is a typo in the condition $d(w, gv) \leq d(w, gv)$. The $g$ should appear only on one side of the inequality.

@feynhat I have fixed the typo, thank you!

@feynhat With respect to the action on $T'$, we assume the action of $G$ on $T$ preserves adjacency, so this action induces an action on $T'$ in the natural way.

They are wrong, the condition 1 is false in general. Maybe they forgot to mention some extra conditions such as minimality of T as a G-invariant tree.
